# Override Cmd+S and Ctrl+S for post submission

Tags: feature-request, keyboard

I know it's probably a bit naughty, but it would be nice for Stack Exchange to prevent the default actions from occurring for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> on its sites. Instead of opening the browser's save dialog box, those commands should submit the current post.

Comment: Just use `TAB` then `SPACE` instead if it really bugs you having to use the mouse.

Comment: **EVEN LOTUS NOTES** uses `CTRL+S` as a SAVE DOCUMENT feature.  Why on earth would you change it?

Comment: in the context of a post, wouldn't the post be the document?

Answer (score 22):

No.

It's up to me to decide how I want to use a website. Same with opening a link in a Window, I decide my browsing habits. I *know* ctrl-s saves the page (or document) it's universally accepted. With questions having a regular auto-save...why is there a need?

If you're still convinced, ask a question over at [UserExperience.SE](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) and see what they say about replacing a well-known key shortcut with a different one.

Comment: because nobody saves a webpage with a form on it, they either want to submit the form by "accidentally" hitting ctrl+s or they mean to save the resultant webpage to file instead of the one with a form on it.

Comment: `because nobody saves a webpage with a form on it` ... so, you now speak for everyone and/or know everyones usage of the site?

Comment: I've never, in 20 years of using the web, hit Ctrl-S to submit a form.  Ctrl-S is "Save". Universally.

Comment: Ask people what they would use Ctrl-S for. I bet 100% of the time you would get "saving" rather than "submit" as an answer.

Comment: yes, you are right. But in that context. What are they "saving", the post. That's what someone is saving at that moment in time.

Comment: Altering the applications default behavior that is generally the default for not just that application but just about every other application on the platform is generally a bad UI decision...

Answer (score 4):

I'm all for a hotkey to post an answer, but why on earth <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>?

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> would make more sense and isn't used for anything right now.